# Google finance - Historical price for last "n" days; How do we show only price and not dates in each row. So results contained in 1 column?

Tags: google-sheets, stock

Say I am looking for GOOG last 5 days. So =googlefinance(B1,"price",StartDate,EndDate) will fetch Date & Price for last 5 days in 2 columns in 5 rows.

Tried something like: =INDEX(googlefinance((B1,"price",B12,B13),"select Col2"))

I am looking to get only the price in 1 column in 5 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - gets prices with header

```
=index(googlefinance((B1,"price",B12,B13),2)
```

To remove header

```
=query(index(googlefinance((B1,"price",B12,B13),2),"select* label Col1 ''")
```